# see tabmenu clicks on google analytics

Tags: menu, google-analytics, tabs

I have a page with tabmenus. Can I tweak google analytics so that i can see which tabs are clicked?
I have this standard snippet on every page.

```
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GA tracking snippet should never be altered or tweaked for any reason as tracking functionality may break. Also, it has nothing to do with how your tab menus are tracked when you click them. That comes down to how you implement the click tracking. For example if you are using GTM (highly recommended), then you simply set up your click listeners and fire your event when those tab menus are clicked. If not using GTM, then you could code up a listener to listen for tab menu clicks, and then fire off an event when they are clicked.

Overly simple example assuming you have jquery:

```
$('.tabClass').click(function(){
    ga('send', 'event', 'tab menu', 'clicked');
})
```

Of if you do it inline:

```
<a href="somelink.html" onlick="ga('send','event','tab menu', 'clicked');">Tab menu link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using this tab script: https://github.com/jellekralt/Responsive-Tabs, so where do I add your code?

Comment: Modified my answer to show how to include the listener inline. Be careful about this though, as it is an overly simplified listener. You will need to change, verify, and QA it.